# wp_trash_post action hook with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions

When a 'contact' cpt post is trashed, I need a metakey from another cpt 'act' to be deleted, I have been searching all over which hook I should use but unfortunately the [codex action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) page is not very helpful. Below is the code I have.

Ideally, I would also like an Admin Notice to be placed in the post listing screen where the user will be redirected to.

Question:

- 1. is this the best hook to be using ?
- 2. Why isn't it working as expected ?

Below the code I have thus far.

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_contact', 'contact_cpt_cleanup' );

function contact_cpt_cleanup( $post_id ){

global $post_type;   
    if ( $post_type != 'contact' ) return;

    // die('deleted contact');

    // check to see if the current contact has any acts attached
    $acts_associated = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'acts_associated', true );

    // if so, delete the association from the act to the contact
    if( $acts_associated ){
        foreach( $acts_associated as $act_id ) {
        delete_post_meta( (int) $act_id, 'contact_associated' );
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.

### EDITS:

Reading this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/trash-post-action-with-custom-post-type) and this [error report](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15628) I now believe the correct syntax for this action hook is `wp_{post_status}_{post_type}` and not `'trash_post'`. But it is still not working.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_trash_post` is literal, not dynamic. It doesn't change and always ends in `_post` regardless of actual post type. See [`wp_trash_post()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_trash_post/):

```
do_action( 'wp_trash_post', $post_id );
```

You also should retrieve post and check its type from `$post_id`, do not use globals in that fashion because they might refer to entirely different post.

Your second theory refers to entirely different hook in [`wp_transition_post_status()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_transition_post_status/):

```
do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post );
```

Note that it doesn't start with `wp_`, however it does contain specific post type in it dymaically, so it will be `trash_contact`.

Comment: looks like i had a few things mixed up, thanks for the info, will try your suggestions and update my post once its working.